# Django model constraint - Sum of all rows for a user less than a constant

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to add a constraint to a Django model to check for the sum of all previous values in the model for a specific user.

```py
Class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.Decimal(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(price__lte=1000), name='weight_lte_1000')
        ]
```

This constraint applies to each entry, but I need another check to make sure the sum of all values of price for books linked to a specific user stays below 1000.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you left out the `constraints = [...]` part in your code; see [the `Meta.constraints` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#constraints)

Comment: One option for this kind of check would be a database trigger (not from inside Django), or another option is Django validation inside the model or form `clean()` method.

Comment: @Ralf You're right, updated.

Comment: @Ralf, I can add it at SQL level but prefer to have everything inside the model. Theoretically, it seems doable at form level, but I can't make sure it will be imposed on admin interface. So looking for a way to implement it at the model level.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't do that only with `CheckConstraints` but I think that you could enclose your model's `save()` method inside a transaction and do the check by yourself there. If the check fails simply raise an exception

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        price_sum = Book.objects.filter(user=self.user).aggregate(price_sum=Sum('price'))['price_sum']  # You probably need some more code to handle corner cases
        if price_sum > 1000:
            raise PriceException()  # Made up exception. This will provoke a rollback
```

Now please note that custom `save()` methods are not used in some situations (particularly in migrations and `.update()`) so this "solution" is not as good as what you wanted but it may be a starting point.